# My sound randomly mutes sometimes in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, vlc, soundcard, emesene

My sound sometimes stops working when I'm playing a video or music on VLC.  This happens when I pause it for a while or skip a part. Also in emesene the sound mutes sometimes and my sound settings sometimes said that the sound is muted without me changing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're using some sort of power-saving packages such as `laptop-mode` or `pm-powersave` that are automatically disabling sound after some idle period?